# Getting Error on adding column to table in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, column

Getting following error

```
Error in file: "/www/Abc/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/sql/abc_bar_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: abc_bar/baz
```

I have created a custom table by following

```
/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/sql/abc_bar_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('abc_bar/baz'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_CLOB, 0, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Name');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->endSetup();
```

I added a custom Grid, and created form like this.

```
/www/Abc/app/code/local/abc/Bar/Block/Adminhtml/Baz/Grid.php
<?php

class Abc_Bar_Block_Adminhtml_Baz_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setId('abc_bar_baz_grid');
    $this->setDefaultDir('asc');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _getCollectionClass() {
    return 'abc_bar/baz_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => $this->__('ID'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '50px',
        'index' => 'id'
            )
    );

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Name'),
        'index' => 'name'
            )
    );

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getRowUrl($row) {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}
}
```

And

```
/www/Abc/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/Block/Adminhtml/Baz/Edit/Form.php
```

```
class Abc_Bar_Block_Adminhtml_Baz_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setId('abc_bar_baz_form');
        $this->setTitle($this->__('Baz Information'));
    }

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $model = Mage::registry('abc_bar');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post'
        ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
            'legend' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Baz Information'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
        ));

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'id',
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));


        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

For this I was following [markoshust](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified). By this a table having two fields id and name has been created.And data is being shown into grid. That's fine. But when I try to add a new column, let say 'sales_emails' by following

```
/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/sql/abc_bar_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('abc_bar/baz'),
          'emails',
           array(
               'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
               'comment' => 'Sales Emails for Order type'
            )
        );

    $installer->endSetup();
```

And I have add  in following

/www/Abc/app/code/local/abc/Bar/Block/Adminhtml/Baz/Grid.php

```
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
    // Add the columns that should appear in the grid
    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => $this->__('ID'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '50px',
        'index' => 'id'
            )
    );

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Name'),
        'index' => 'name'
            )
    );

    $this->addColumn('emails', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Emails'),
        'index' => 'emails'
            )
    );


    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

And in

```
/www/Abc/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/Block/Adminhtml/Baz/Edit/Form.php
    protected function _prepareForm() {
    $model = Mage::registry('abc_bar');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post'
    ));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Baz Information'),
        'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'id',
        ));
    }

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('emails', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'emails',
        'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Emails'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Emails'),
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

And my config.xml is

```
/www/Abc/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Bar>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </Abc_Bar>
    </modules>

<global>
    <helpers>
        <abc_bar>
            <!-- This is where we define our helper directory -->
            <class>Abc_Bar_Helper</class>
        </abc_bar>
    </helpers>

    <blocks>
        <abc_bar>
            <!-- Set a block definition and lookup directory -->
            <class>Abc_Bar_Block</class>
        </abc_bar>
    </blocks>

    <models>
        <abc_bar>
            <!-- This is where we define our model directory -->
            <class>Abc_Bar_Model</class>
            <!-- Define a resource to create a custom table -->
            <resourceModel>abc_bar_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </abc_bar>

        <!-- Here's our resource model we'll use to create a database table -->
        <abc_bar_mysql4>
            <class>Abc_Bar_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <!-- Let's define our table, we'll call it with the baz name, but the real table is abc_bar_baz -->
                <!-- After we define our entity, we can call it with our model by calling abc_bar/baz -->
                <baz>
                    <table>abc_bar_baz</table>
                </baz>
            </entities>
        </abc_bar_mysql4>
    </models>

    <!-- And finally we define our resource setup script -->
    <resources>
        <abc_bar_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Abc_Bar</module>
            </setup>
        </abc_bar_setup>
    </resources>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <!-- This is how we load our Adminhtml controllers -->
                <modules>
                    <Abc_Bar before="Mage_Adminhtml">Abc_Bar_Adminhtml</Abc_Bar>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <abc_bar>
                <!--
                We again keep a nice naming convention and make our module upgrade proof by placing it in a separate folder
                - Since we are in the adminhtml node, this will look for the XML file in the app/design/adminhtml/default/default root folder
                -->
                <file>abc/bar.xml</file>
            </abc_bar>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

I have updated by sq version in config file, 
I am getting following error, what is missing in above process.

```
Error in file: "/www/Abc/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/sql/abc_bar_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: abc_bar/baz
```

Comment: @Qaisar Satti,,

Comment: Please post your `config.xml` file

Comment: @ Digital Pianism file posted

Comment: As said earlier, it is working fine for two field, On adding 3rd field it behave like this

Comment: Refresh your cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I have made following change in

```
/app/code/local/Abc/Bar/sql/abc_bar_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0
```

I used **abc_bar-baz**, which is my table mane in bd, I know this is strange, I have already used  **"/"** at multipule place for creating new table and updating existing table, but for now it is not working. So Use

```
->addColumn($installer->getTable('abc_bar-baz')
```

instead of

```
->addColumn($installer->getTable('abc_bar/baz')
```